# How to pass multiple values in THEN clause in CASE statement sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use multiple values in THEN clause of CASE statement in Sql Server 2008?

e.g.

```
Select CASE Country
           WHEN 'UNITED' THEN Country In ('ABC United','ABS United','X')
           WHEN 'CORE' THEN country in ('p','q','r')
```

So basically here my United and core are agrregated values and when selected by user , I want to pass respective values in then clause (Which are non-aggregated)
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want when `Country` is `'UNITED'`?

Comment: Are you looking to select/return a different set of values for each case.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*, not a statement. It produces *a* value. Also, it's not clear what you're trying to do here since you seem to have a predicate in the `THEN` clauses, and that's not valid within the `select` clause. If these are actually meant to be filtering rows (e.g. this is intended to be in the `where` clause), I'd suggest you look again at what you're trying to do and consider whether you just need to put all of the conditions plainly in the query and link them with boolean `and`s and `or`s.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. It looks like when `Country = 'UNITED'`, you want to return the boolean result (true or false) for `Country In ('ABC United','ABS United','X')`, but well, that result is false obviously, as country is 'UNITED', not 'ABC United', not 'ABS United', and not 'X'. Same for Country = 'CORE' where it cannot be  in ('p','q','r'), because 'CORE' is not in that list. That means what you have so far is `select false`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see how old this request is. Why did it suddenly pop up again in "Top Questions"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something based on:

```
DECLARE @Country as varchar(20)
SELECT @Country = 'United'

IF @Country = 'UNITED'
    SELECT '1', '2'
IF @Country = 'CORE'
    SELECT '3', '4'
```

I am sure there are neater ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT CASE Country
            WHEN 'UNITED'
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN Country IN (
                                'ABC United'
                                ,'ABS United'
                                ,'X'
                                )
                            THEN Country
                        ELSE ''
                        END
            WHEN 'CORE'
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN country IN (
                                'p'
                                ,'q'
                                ,'r'
                                )
                            THEN country
                        ELSE ''
                        END
            ELSE ''
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snip-it of code from a where clause where I needed it to return multiple values:

```
AND CASE '{EOC_TEST_TYPE}'::text 
        WHEN 'NGSYB' THEN t.short_name IN ('EB1','NGS')
        WHEN 'NGSH3' THEN t.short_name IN ('EAH','NGS') 
        WHEN 'NGSIV' THEN t.short_name IN ('NGS','ECS')
        ELSE t.short_name = LEFT('{EOC_TEST_TYPE}'::text,3)
    END
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?